# blind/visually impaired - Redirect to Accessible website

Tags: accessibility

Is there a way to add something on selected page on a web site that said to people using accessible software, like NVDA, to go to the page X for full accessibility.

I have some page with a lot of thing hard to make accessible and keeping the user design.

Think like a mobile page where you can redirect to mobile.mysite.com

I want mysite.com/mySelectedFolder/index.xyz?accessibilty=on
This page will remove all user graphic, javascript and other things that cause difficulty to NVDA. Probably change the way that some of the data are showed.

Is this a bad things to do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NVDA but does it manipulate the browser by sending extra headers, disable javascript or adding/removing things from the page?

Comment: Having a separate "accessible version" is generally discouraged - as you now have two separate sites to maintain (and screenreader users often end up with a lesser experience or missing functionality). Screenreaders _can_ work with javascript and graphics when the appropriate techniques are used; the preferred approach is to write accessible pages that us these techniques so they can be used by all users. Are there specific issues you are running into that are causing problems? It may be better to ask about how to solve those first before bailing and looking to have a separate site.

Comment: Additionally, not all users with impairments are using software like screenreaders, e.g. Color-blind, people with mobility issues so they rely on the keyboard.

Comment: jazZRo, NVDA and other assistive tech don't manipulate the browser, they rely on the brower's accessibility API for info about the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WCAG 2.0 allows an alternate version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26188033/1591669), but

- you need to make sure that the inaccessible page is accessible to a certain extent (otherwise your users would not be able to access the link to the accessible page on the inaccessible page), and
- you have to provide "all of the same information and functionality".

There is no reliable machine-readable way to detect that a user would benefit from or require an accessible page. Not all visually impaired users use screen readers (and even if, you can’t detect every screen reader use).

I’d in almost all cases try to avoid creating alternate versions. Make one page for all, and make it accessible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to notify your users that an accessible version exists, but only those needing it, I suggest having a hidden link at the top of your page (as in literally the first element in your body).

The code is fairly simple to do. Example HTML and CSS below will give you a link that is not visible on the page unless it has focus (which most sighted users will never trigger).

HTML

```
<a class="assistive-text" href="http://yoursite.com/accessible version">Go to Accessible Version of this site</a>
```

CSS

```
.assistive-text {
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  position: absolute !important;
}
.assistive-text:focus {
  clip: auto !important;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100000;
  /* everything below this comment is just for the look */
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

If you want it for every page on your site, then you might want to generate the link based on the link of the current page (but that's a whole other discussion).

I have to agree with BrendanMcK's comment that it's not a great idea to make a separate accessible version of your site though. Most screen readers can deal with JavaScript and graphics just fine, and there are frameworks out there (like jQuery-UI) that are supposed to be accessible to begin with. Fixing issues encountered in screen readers usually helps your regular users too.

Comment: Not all visually impaired users use a screen reader, so the visually hidden link will be hidden for them, too.

Comment: Is that a problem? The question revolves around screen readers and creating a link to an alternate version specifically for those who use them.