# Can you have a separate CSS WCAG stylesheet and meet WCAG accessibility requirements?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

I work on a large company's website. The company would like to meet WCAG AA requirements. There are clashes between the website branding and accessibility rules (colors mainly). I would prefer to separate the styles from the current branding styles (current website) an also have a WCAG version of the site.

My question is: Can I create two separate CSS stylesheets one for average web users and another for WCAG users? Will this meet requirements?

For instance; If I create a button that the user can choose WCAG version or regular styled version of the site. Will this satisfy WCAG requirements or do all style choices have to be WCAG compliant?

Comment: Relevant (possibly duplicate) questions: [Accessible toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26168231/1591669), [blind/visually impaired - Redirect to Accessible website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27131214/1591669). And on UX SE: [Having a separate accessible page for screen reader users](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/105064/17023)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article seems to imply you can - provided the controls to switch to the accessible stylesheet are accessible themselves (it would be ironic if it wasn't, sort-of like labelling language-translation options in a program in English)

https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C29.html

> an author provides alternative views of the content by providing controls that adjust the CSS that is used to control the visual presentation of content. Controls provided within the Web page allow users to select or modify the presentation in a way that meets the success criterion at the level claimed.

Comment: Yep, one can also see [How to meet (minimum contrast)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/?showtechniques=143#qr-visual-audio-contrast-contrast) and particularly G174 technique. An example of a styleswitcher: https://oui.sncf ("Accessibilité" in french. It lacks from the UK site probably because it already is contrasted enough :) Note that tabbing with keyboard works fine)