# Toggle Accessibility for a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, accessibility

I am working on a toggle button for enabling/disabling accessibility on a website. Similar to that in iphones.

For example, on the canada.ca government website, they shouldn't have italics but clients rarely consider accessibility when writing their contents.

I was thinking of this idea but I'm not sure if it's a good solution.
Any suggestions/feedback?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by enabling/disabling accessibility?

Comment: Didn't understand your idea

Comment: you have to come up with a better example :)

Comment: What do you want from us

Comment: I want some feedback if it is a good idea to replicate the accessibility button option in iphones and put it in a website.

Comment: It's always a good idea to think about your readers ease to read. ;) And there can be many ways to achieve it. Standards exist about that topic... A good start point is here: https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility

Comment: Some good info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168231/accessible-toggle

Answer (score 0):

You will have to think about everything you wish to change in order to improve "accessibility"... Or be it "readability".

Example:

- italic
- fonts smaller than __ px
- font colors
- etc.

So if you taugth about it just a bit, at writting time, by adding some classes... A `data` attribute can be used to match them and provide a button to toggle these classes out.

Then, the user could "remove those harder to read styles.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#control button").on("click",function(){
    $("*[data-readability]").each(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass($(this).data("readbility"));
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.small{
  font-size:0.4em;
}
.italic{
  font-style:italic;
}
.yellow{
  color:yellow;
}

#control{
  position:fixed;
  top:0.5em;
  right:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="page">
<span class="small" data-readability="small">This is real small fonts.</span> <span class="italic" data-readability="italic">This is italics.</span> <span class="yellow" data-readability="yellow">This is a hard to read color.</span>
</div>

<div id="control"><button>Click here for a better readability</button></div>
```

So if all the styling left is not a problem to readbility... And the page still is acceptably nice, that's a way.

Now *what* can possibly be a problem to readability and accessibility is defined somewhere [here](https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility).

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is better than having no accessibility, however by using semantic HTML generally it is not hard to make sites accessible so I would just work on making the page/site accessible as a whole and not only based off a toggle.