# Is an alternative version of each page in a site a valid approach to WCAG 2.0?

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

We are working on a new project that requires a complex design, however the client also wants it to be WCAG 2.0 compliant level AA. So we came up with the idea of adding a toolbar at the top of the each page with a button saying something along the lines "view this page enhanced for accessibility" and then store the preference as a cookie.

The question is if this is considered discrimination or a technique that would be easily missed and defeat the goal? We have ways of making this switch button very obvious, but we haven't seen any site doing something like this, nor have found any documentation in favor or against it.

Comment: Do the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26168231/1591669) answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

Technically, yes - it's a valid approach to WCAG 2.0 - but you won't find many accessibility specialists recommending this.

The WCAG 2.0 supporting documents provide a lot of context for this, in [Understanding Conforming Alternate Versions](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/conformance#uc-conforming-alt-versions-head).  However it clearly advises against this approach, at the end of the section called "[Why permit alternate versions?](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/conformance#uc-whypermit-head)":

> Note that providing an alternate version is a fallback option for conformance to WCAG and the preferred method of conformance is to make all content directly accessible.

Compare the reasons given there to the situation with your own website, and only go down this route if you're certain you can't achieve conformance in the main version.  If you can make the majority of your pages accessible in the main version, it's OK to have alternative versions for a few pages.

Part of your question concerns discrimination:

> The question is if this is considered discrimination or a technique that would be easily missed and defeat the goal?

WCAG 2.0 doesn't really address discrimination *per se*, but local statutes likely do.  This isn't the place for legal advice.

My own view is that going to lots of effort to provide (and maintain) alternative versions doesn't really amount to discrimination, but it doesn't aspire to inclusion either.  Imagine a public library: an old building, with steps leading up to a grand front entrance.  Pedestrians can stroll inside, enjoy the beautiful atrium, see posters about current events, talk to a librarian, or just go straight to the books.  A wheelchair user has to go to the rear entrance, then ring a bell for a librarian to come and let them in.  No fancy atrium to enjoy.  The librarian has to let them out again, too.  While the library is accessible for wheelchair users, the experience is a bit second-class; it's accessible by "alternative accommodations". Ideally the grand front entrance would be accessible to wheelchair users, but the architecture has a protected status.  Websites are easier to improve than buildings, so it's better to avoid alternative versions.

Your mention of a "toolbar" to provide "enhanced accessibility" is worth exploring a bit further.  Are your alternative versions really fully-fledged pages, or merely the same page with some tweaks applied? Providing customization options for the user is also a valid approach - see the [Fluid Infusion Preferences Framework](https://fluidproject.org/infusion.html) project for an example of this.  The relevant WCAG techniques are:

- [C29: Using a style switcher to provide a conforming alternate version](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/C29)
- [SCR38: Creating a conforming alternate version for a web page designed with progressive enhancement](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/SCR38)
- [SVR4: Allowing users to provide preferences for the display of conforming alternate versions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/SVR4).

Comment: very well put, @andrewmacpherson.  some people get very touchy when it comes to alternate sites and discrimination but your answer was very emotionless, in a good way (like Spock :-)).

Answer (score 1):

Two pages is acceptable but a bad idea, maintainability, SEO etc. are all factors as have been mentioned.

But what hasn't been mentioned is simply having different style sheets for accessibility.

Provided your html mark-up is valid and logically structured then to make the page accessible is a 'simple' case of adding aria attributes - that covers users with screen readers.

You said this was a complex page so the 'constraints' of designing for disabled users may make you simplify and improve components along the way and so benefit the client anyway. Changing your HTML to be accessible not only benefits your disabled users but you will find it makes the site easier to user for able bodied users, so that's a plus.

Once your HTML is valid and adjusted for accessibility to screen readers the other parts of accessibility (for partially sighted, colour blind etc.) are easily achieved with a different style sheet (or several for different scenarios.)

Disabled users need many different things but the key focus should be that the site is usable at 400% zoom on a 1920 * 1080 screen, colours can be changed, fonts can be changed and animations can be disabled for users with cognitive impairements.

This can all be handled with CSS.

What I did on my own site was to have a standard style sheet without animations, standard colours etc. Then a seperate style sheet for:

1. animations (included by default)
2. colours (over-riding standard colours without the use of !important)
3. No JavaScript - as this can be a real issue for certain things and screen readers (i hide certain elements that would cause confusion without javascript enabled)

This is augmented by a seperate settings page where users can select font size, colours, font family, animations or not, images or not etc. stored in localstorage and then processed into some simple classes on the body on each page load that can be used for fine-grained control over items.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered by the following WCAG technique : [G136: Providing a link at the beginning of a nonconforming Web page that points to a conforming alternate version](http://%20https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G136.html)

This could be very cool, but it's not realistic.

20% of the population have direct benefit for accessibility:

- using zoom,
- getting correct contrast (color blindness, ...),
- having readable fonts (dyslexia),
- using simple language (foreigners, cognitive disabilities, deaf born people),
- using keyboard accessible controls (motor impairment due to age or accident).

Definitely, if you manage to provide an accessible version for 20% of the population, why would you want to hide it ?

Is because I may be dyslexic that I would want to have an ugly black and white page?

If you want to provide a toolbar, then you should give different options : enhance the page for color blind people, enhance for blind people, enhance for low vision, enhance for screen magnifiers, enhance for dyslexic, enhance for motor impairments, ...

Answer (score -1):

It's generally a bad idea to double every page of your website. You'd better make the primary site accessible.

Don't forget that it will double your maintenance work.
It will also eventually happen, perhaps tomorrow or perhaps in 3 years, and this despite all the care you can have, that an accessible page will be out of date compared to the normal version, because someone just forgot to do something somewhere at some moment in the organization managing the site.
An oversight can have incidious consequences and you will probably take a long time to notice it, and if ever you become aware of it.

Note that if you can update an accessible page automatically when a normal one is modified, you can very probably make the normal site accessible at the first place.

Several studies and sureveys (example: webaim) show that, if a text only or more accessible version of a page is available, most of the users for which it could be useful don't open it at all.
Beside the possible difficulty to find the link or button, the main reason for this is because they basicly know that such pages are likely to be forgotten, out of date, buggy, or not that carefully maintained as the normal ones.

Comment: In the most recent WebAIM survey results that included the question about a text-only version (survey #5), 29.3% said they seldom or never use the alternate version compared with 41.1% that responded always or often (26.1% said sometimes)